# Timeout and Retry-Backoff mechanisms in msgraph-sdk-java

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, throttling, microsoft-graph-sdks, batching, retry-logic

I have recently started using msgraph-sdk for java for creating a syncing service for oneDrive users, files etc.
I want to make few calls via batching like getting permissions info for multiple files.
Does the sdk support batched calls. If yes, can someone point me to the documentation or some sample code for the same.

Also, in case of throttling errors such as 429 or timeout errors, I want to add a backoff and retry logic to most of the calls.
Is there a way to set some config while creating a IGraphServiceClient object to do the retry-backoff logic.

Comment: These features are under active consideration. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-design. Please watch the repo for developments: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java

Comment: @MichaelMainer Thanks for the update on this.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your throttling question, yes, you can configure the [RetryHandler](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-core/blob/4db7fcefe4a1762978df14a639c5bbc2710851c3/src/main/java/com/microsoft/graph/httpcore/RetryHandler.java). There is a RetryOptions object that you can configure. But that may not be necessary since there is already logic that supports retry in the default retry handler.

`public RetryOptions(IShouldRetry shouldRetry, int maxRetries, long delay)`

Comment: Hey Michael, do you also know how to do it?